# Java code development without continuous maven build, deploy and tomcat restart n spring application

Tags: java, spring, testing, mocking, development-environment

1. My spring application required maven-build and deploy and tomcat restart for each and every java changes. Is there any tool or way to avoid these processes to speed up my java development?
2. How can we mock a real-time java object that can use and test in the main class?
3. Is there any way to speed up debugging and testing and editing java codes (with some trial and run
   codes)

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems normal that Tomcat needs to restart for every change since it is essentially re-deploying the deployable (WAR,JAR etc) and re-publishing it to ensure latest changes are available when it is accessed.
2. You could use mocked objects in Junit test suites. It is not advisable to test using the main class. For mocking, you could use libraries like (Mockito, Powermockito etc.)

3.Unfortunately no. Debugging will take time but as you gain experience you will become better at it. (For eg: a simple way to find what caused an exception, is to read the stack trace or e.printStacktrace and you can see what line caused it)

Comment: If a method which has only one object (as method parameter) to populate data and for that object I have to navigate through whole in my application. Is there any way to mock that object (non serializable object) ?Mockito will help for this ?

Comment: I am not sure whether i understood correctly, but mockito can help you with mocking anything. Unit Tests should not test the entire flow of the application but only pieces of it. I think you could use ArgumentMatchers in Mockito or the when(methodCall).thenReturn(theValueYouWant).

Answer (score 0):

1. There are some technique out there allow you to do so, but it requires significant effort to configure that (install Java agent in your JVM), and it might not work perfectly if your project is very complex. You can take a look on hot-reload or hot-swap ([this](https://www.jrebel.com/blog/java-hotswap-guide)). Or, you can deploy to jetty for primary testing before you move on to tomcat, there is a maven plugin for jetty which you can easily configure hot reload for it.
2. What do you mean "real-time java object "? Can you post an example, basically you can mock anything with java mocking framework, but it is better you are using TDD approaches, or else you might have difficulties in mocking some features for example `private method` or `static method`.
3. The easiest way is to attach debugger to your running JVM. Then you can use your IDE to real time debugging, which basically allow you to inspect all your object value, so you don't have to keep on injecting `System.out.println` and re-deploy your project. And some debugger allow you to real time modify your java code, which indirectly it will modify your byte code, and you can see your result on the fly.

Comment: If a method which has only one object (as method parameter) to populate data and for that object I have to navigate through whole in my application. Is there any way to mock that object (non serializable object) ?Mockito will help for this ?

Comment: @Arun yes, there are few ways to do so, I don't get what you mean `for that object I have to navigate through whole in my application`, easiest is to use `spy` in Mockito, you can refer this https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html